# What does "they're pretty strict on refunds" mean?

Tags: meaning

please assist me with this sentence because I can't understand it.

Comment: When someone asks to accept something and this something has already cancelled. So the person who asked it said "they are pretty strict on refunds".

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it would mean that they will not give a refund, unless the person asking for the refund has proof that they are entitled to it.

For instance a company might not give a refund unless the purchaser can produce a receipt.